# How to draw rectangle on screen showing where appbar window will dock

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, drawing

I'm working on a class that descends from the WPF `Window` class that implements the Application Toolbar functionality available in the Window 7 + shell (that is, it calls the Win32 `SHAppBarWindow` to dock to an edge of the desktop and undock).  The idea is that you can drag the window around the screen and when it is within some distance of a desktop edge, it docks itself.

Because of the need to call the Win32 `SHAppbarWindow` function, and because working through WPF events is just not helpful, I've written a window procedure that works at the Win32 level & is hooked in using the `HwndSource.AddHook` method.  This procedure gets called first and processes anything it needs to process, and passes the rest on to WPF.

I've been working on the dragging logic and I'd like to give the user a visual indication that the window could dock itself to the edge it's closest to, without actually docking it.  To that end, I'd like to display a transparent rectangle with a dashed border the size that the window would be after docking in the location it would be.  If the user releases the left mouse button at that point, then the window would actually be docked at that edge. Once the mouse is moved away from that edge, the rectangle would go away.

I know how to compute the rectangle's size & location. But how do I display the rectangle?  I'm pretty sure I'd have to do it with GDI32 calls, as the target area is outside the window's nonclient & client areas.  But how would I draw the rectangle, without messing up the other windows that might be in that area?

Comment: Create a layered (WIN32) or transparent (WPF) window on which to draw the target rectangle.

Comment: @arx:  Interesting idea.  So I would create a layered window when the drag starts that's the same size as the desktop and has no non-client area & is transparent.  When I detect that the window would dock, I draw my rectangle on that window & erase it when done or the window moves away from that position.  Then, when the move finishes, I destroy the window.  Right?

Comment: Yes.  Layered windows can be quite inefficient if aero isn't in use, so I'd keep the window hidden while there's no rectangle to display, and I would resize the window to match the rectangle.